# Date format in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

[image: Date Fromat]

Edited: Want to convert the format.

I am kinda new in BigQuery, recently I was working on a project. I want to convert above type of format into yyyy/mm/dd format. How will I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) with [FORMAT_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) to get the desired output:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d",PARSE_DATE("%B %d, %Y","June 10, 2014")) AS date_str
```

`PARSE_DATE` will parse the provided string into a DATE type value in BQ format (YYYY-MM-DD) and then `FORMAT_DATE` will format this DATE to a string with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is wondering how to convert the whole column;
FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d",PARSE_DATE("%B %d, %Y",ColumnName)) as DesiredColumnName